# Can't close the window with Electron and Socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, electron

I started a chat application project with NodeJS and Socket io, everything was fine.

Later i decided to add my app to the Electron framework, the chat start in a window, but i can't close this window, the exit button do nothing.

After some research on my code to understand where the problem came from, i deleted the socket.io.js line in my main.html and then i could close my app, but for sure all my client Websocket stop working.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Here's my createWindow function from my main.js.

```
function createWindow () {

  // Instantiate Express App
  app.server = require(__dirname + '/app/app')();

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow();
  // win.maximize();

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL('http://localhost:'+config.server.port);
  // Open the DevTools.
  // win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.focus();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    console.log("close");
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  });
}
```

My project file tree look's like this

```
main.js // Electron, create the window load the app.js
/app/app.js // Express, all my socket function
/views/main.html // Html
```

Please help me !

Answer (score 3):

erff resolved in my main.html i had this function, after deleting everything ok !

```
  /** 
  * Alert when user leave the page
  * 
  */
  window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
      event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
      event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
  }
```